# Google font - how to specific font-family If they have the same name?

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

I'm tried to use Google fonts for my html page.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I expect that the name of the font-family is different instead is the same

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Montserrat-Regular'), url (http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v6/zhcz-_WihjSQC0oHJ9TCYPk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2) format('woff2');
unicode-range: ..
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
src: local('Montserrat-Bold'), url (http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v6/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcoWiMMZ7xLd792ULpGE4W_Y.woff2) format('woff2');
unicode-range: ..
}
```

I tried to do this but with no success.

```
.one {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
two {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

How can I define the two different fonts in my css?
Thank you

Comment: It should work perfectly due the different font-weight. Can you make a stacksnippet or a jsfiddle.net to show the issue?

Comment: maybe the missing `.` before `two`? or only a typo on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working, but you are missing the point (`.`) in front of the `two` on CSS. See the following snippet:

```css
.one {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.two {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<span class="one">This is text on "one" with weight 700</span><br/>
<span class="two">This is text on "two" with weight 400</span>
```